# Nginx chock down

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, nginx

In my production environment i had nginx-1.6.0 as proxy server and tomcat-7 at backend installed on AWS. On random pattern the site was going down because nginx was getting chock down and was not receiving any traffic although tomcat was running fine all the time.
I even upgraded the nginx version to 1.10.2 (latest stable) but this behavior continues.
I have checked everything, server was having average traffic, there was no error in logs during this period. there is just a increase in CPU % at this time window.
But if only increase in cpu % is the reason then why is tomcat not showing any error ?

Not sure what is the exact reason, please help !

Comment: What does "chock down" mean? Are you using a T2 instance?

Comment: Yes, I am using t2.medium instance.
chock down means- it stops accepting any connections through browser (GUI) or CLI , although nginx process runs normally for this time window.
and after some time it becomes normal again.

Comment: Check the CPU credits during that time.